Some tantrik text books and sampradaya for mahavidya upasana
As a resident of West Bengal , India, I have only seen the Dakshineswar Kali Devi , and the tarapith tara Devi, the two foremost mahavidyas. But where can I find the temples of all the other mahavidyas? Also how can a normal householder start the Upasana of the mahavidyas to attain either a blessing or moksha ? What are some English text books which can enlighten us about the mahavidya and practical methods to get their blessings ? Thank you.
